# Compatible tag in Android Manifest file

Tags: android

```
<compatible-screens >
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    </compatible-screens>
```

I have written this code to support only **240x320** screen resolutions. It is filtering as per my need. But now I want this .apk file to also support **240x400** and **240x432** screen resolutions.

Now is it possible to add this tag also to the above existing code:

```
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
```

So that using this apk we can support all three screen resolution. Because I have done this application using multiple apk.

Comment: if my solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this way:

```
   <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Check this Reference for better explanations :

[compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

Comment: Need to add xxhdpi devices as well :( Something like this...As of now there is no better way to do this
         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
      <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />

Answer (score 1):

Try this it would be better

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

for more info try [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html